# Using another function but with different properties in function under the same class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter, I know this is basic OOP but still is it possible and how? Here is my code, I want to use this:

```
$this->applogin();
```

inside this function:

```
public function fblogin() {

    //use it here...
    $this->applogin();
}
```

they both share the same class. But I want to change some of the properties inside `$this->applogin();` to tailor them for use in this new `fblogin()` function. Mainly change `$email = $this->input->post('email');` to `$email = new data;` How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Foo
{
    private $email;
    private $pwd;

    public function fblogin()
    {
        // for example sake...
        $this->email = 'me@test.com';

        $this->applogin('test@test.com', 'pwd');

        print $this->email; // 'test@test.com'
    }

    public function applogin($email, $pwd)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->pwd = $pwd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to declare variable in class? Can't I access the variable form within the function? Its a big class I don't want to make things messy

Comment: What If I can override that variable somehow? I really need the whole function just different data for 2 variables

Comment: Does the class expect to use `$email` throughout several of its functions? In which case, you want the variable declared as I have explained. In my example, you are accessing the variable from within the function

Comment: In which case, it seems to me that you want two different variables. Perhaps I don't understand your question..

Comment: I want to use all the stuff that is going on inside the applogin() function and ran it! Just change its 2 variables: email and password

Comment: Does my edit help. You pass the new values into the function using `function parameters`

Comment: Its a bit confusing, I want to change 2 variables inside applogin() and RAN it inside **fblogin()**

Comment: My example does exactly that. It changes 2 variables to the values that you pass to it, and `fblogin` then accesses those new values. If this is difficult to understand, you may be running before you can walk

Comment: do the variables have to be declared in class?

Comment: If you want to use the variable across multiple functions within the class, then yes, that is the cleanest and best way. If the variable only needs to exist in one function, then no, just create it in the function, and you can't access it from any other function. However, you can return the value from the function, and then use it.

Comment: Let me ask it this way then. How can I return the value from the function, overwrite it and then use it?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back. You are asking very entry level questions, whilst attempting to code in an Object Oriented way, which is beyond that level. I recommend that you read a beginner PHP book, you will no doubt have all of your answers after the first few chapters